# mysql_connect is setting php headers

Tags: php, mysql, http-headers

My PHP script will ultimately insert into a MySQL database, I've got so far as to validate the variables and for some reason redirecting a user back to the addserver.php with header() is reporting the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/includes/mysql.php:2) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/scripts/addserver.php on line 61
```

This is the content of addserver.php (located at /scripts/addserver.php, not to be confused with addserver.php which is the HTML form page)

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
session_start();
// must be logged in
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('location: /login.php?from=/addserver.php');
    exit();
}

// initialise errors array
$errors = array();

// connect to mysql
require('../includes/mysql.php');

// check name
if(empty($_POST['name'])) {
    array_push($errors, 'The server name field is required');
}
if(!strlen($_POST['name'])>=5 || !strlen($_POST['name'])<=30) {
    array_push($errors, 'Server name must be 5-30 characters long');
}
// check ip
if(empty($_POST['ip'])) {
    array_push($errors, 'IP address field is required');
}
if(!filter_var($_POST['ip'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && !preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9]{2,100})\.([a-z\.]{2,8})$/i", $_POST['ip'])) {
    array_push($errors, 'IP address must be in valid x.x.x.x format and submitted without port.');
}
$ip = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ip']));
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM servers WHERE ip='$ip'"))) {
    array_push($errors, 'Server IP has already been registered');
}
// check port
if(empty($_POST['port'])) {
    array_push($errors, 'Port is a required field');
}
if(!$_POST['port']>=1024 || !$_POST['port']<=65535) {
    array_push($errors, 'Port number must be 1024-65535');
}
if(!is_integer(intval($_POST['port']))) {
    array_push($errors, 'Port must be an integer (whole number)');
}
// check website link (not required)
if(!empty($_POST['website'])) {
    if(!filter_var($_POST['website'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)===false) {
        // try adding the http on
        $website = 'http://'.$_POST['website'];
        // try validation again
        if(!filter_var($website, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)===false) {
            array_push($errors, 'Website URL must be valid');
        }
    }
}
// do banner upload later

// if errors are set, send back with errors array as a session var.
if(count($errors)!=1) {
    $_SESSION['adderrors'] = $errors;
    header('location: /addserver.php');
    // end script
    exit('Some variables were invalid.');
}
?>
```

This is the contents of mysql.php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('findmcservers');
?>
```

Comment: Is there any whitespace (spaces, blank lines, etc) in your MySQL.php file outside of the `<?php` and `?>` tags?

Comment: @MarkBaker Annoyingly there is not, I've already checked for this.

Comment: Then you've probably identified a pretty major bug in PHP: the error message clearly identifies line 2 of mysql.php as the line generating the output.... if there's no output there, and nothing there that might generate an error output, then there's a serious fault

Comment: @MarkBaker mysql_connect is not supposed to output anything, and I'm including that file all over my site to connect to MySQL - something is definitely up

Comment: If the file doesn't generate that error anywhere else where you're including it, make sure that it is the correct file that you're including, and that you don't have some other mysql.php file hiding somewhere in a subfolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the closing php tag (?>) in those php files. I've seen some hosts treat them differently.